# Way to hide blank columns in Table Calc in same sheet as field being calculated? (Tableau)

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-columns

When using table calculations to compare the Current period vs. the Previous period in the same sheet, is there a way to hide the blank columns without also hiding the field being calculated? I am wanting to keep everything in the same sheet to avoid having to scroll multiple sheets.

Table Calc blanks (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJ31w.jpg)

Tried putting the table calculations in separate sheets, but that gives an undesired result when having to scroll - would have to scroll both sheets.

Idea of Solution (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLN77.jpg)

Would like it to be all in one line and all in the same sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you?

Maybe you could share how you built it (images or even a workbook), the level of detail and calculations used.

This way others could try to replicate it and come up with ideas and workarounds.

Thanks

[Example using calculated fields to reach a similar result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKGEK.png)

**Formulas**

Current Month:

```
IF MONTH([Order Date]) = MONTH(TODAY())
    THEN [Sales]
END
```

Previous Month:

```
IF MONTH([Order Date]) = MONTH(TODAY())-1
    THEN [Sales]
END
```

Difference:

```
SUM([Current Month])-SUM([Previous Month])
```

Difference %:

```
(SUM([Current Month])-SUM([Previous Month]))
/
ABS(SUM([Current Month]))
```

I used the 'Sample - Superstore' as the data source. Tableau Desktop Version 2019.1.2